# Fila de una tabla en SmallDateTime , no puedo cargar algunas fechas y otras si. (mismo formato)

Tags: sql-server

Agradecería que me ayudasen con el siguiente error en SQL SERVER.

Estoy intentando añadir datos de forma masiva que me han pasado en un .SQL , tengo una tabla llamada "producto" con un campo llamado "fabricación" que indica el año de fabricación de cada producto insertado. ese campo ya lo tengo marcado como "SmallDateTime"

El problema es que cuando ejecuto la instrucción para añadir el listado de productos me lanza el siguiente error:

"The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Lo que más me extraña es que hay productos con el formato de la fecha exactamente iguales ej: 24/08/2020  y  15/05/2019   y en uno me tira el error y en el otro no!

A continuación copio el Script que ejecuto y el log que me devuelve por consola.  Si os fijais me está dando el error en productos con aparentemente valores del mismo tipo en todos los campos...

A alguien se le ocurre que está pasando?¿

Soy novato!!!  MUCHAS GRACIAS!

AQUÍ ABAJO EL SCRIPT QUE EJECUTO.

---

```
insert into Producto
(nombre,precio,modelo,cantidad,marca,fabricacion,valoracion)
values
('Placa Base',40.50,'HTX 500',6,'Asus','20200130',7.0)

insert into Producto
values
('Tarjeta gráfica',110.99,'Óptima',4,'Nvidia','29-01-2020 12:30',6.9)

insert into Producto
values
('Placa base',60.49,'PBX 12',6,'Gigabyte','29/01/2020',7.0) 

insert into Producto
values
('Tarjeta Sonido',99.99,'Sound Class',8,'Sound Blaster',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,8.0)

insert into Producto
(nombre,precio,modelo,cantidad,marca)
values
('Monitor',130,'UltraVision',1,'LG')

insert into Producto
values
('Procesador',190.75,'I5 6000',10,'Intel','19/05/2020',8.3)

insert into Producto
values
('Procesador',230.10,'I7 7500',10,'Intel','14/02/2020 11:30',8.5)

insert into Producto
values
('Procesador',310.05,'I9 Ultra',6,'Intel','14/02/2020 12:30',9.5)

insert into Producto
values
('Procesador',290.12,'Ryzen 7',6,'AMD','14/02/2020 17:45',9.2)

insert into Producto
values
('Procesador',110.22,'Pentium III',10,'Intel','26/02/1999',3.5)

insert into Producto
values
('Memoria RAM',55.95,'DDR3 Extreme 8GB',6,'Kingston',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,5.5)

insert into Producto
values
('Memoria RAM',29.90,'DDR4 4GB',16,'Kingston','15/02/2020',4.9)

insert into Producto
values
('Memoria RAM',130.90,'DDR4 16GB',10,'Toshiba','28/02/2020',5.3)

insert into Producto
values
('Tarjeta Gráfica',130.45,'Extreme 1.0',6,'AMD','18/02/2018',5.4)

insert into Producto
values
('Tarjeta Gráfica',310.80,'Extreme 2.0',6,'AMD','28/02/2019',6.4)

insert into Producto
values
('Tarjeta Gráfica',530.99,'Extreme 3.0 Gaming',6,'AMD','01/03/2020',8.6)

insert into Producto
values
('Tarjeta Gráfica',615.25,'Extreme 4.0 Gaming WoW',4,'AMD','11/04/2020',9.8)

insert into Producto
values
('Tarjeta Sonido',100.20,'Sound Max',1,'Sound Blaster','04/03/2017',8.0)

insert into Producto
values
('Fuente alimentacion',34.50,'ATX4',6,'Gigabyte','13/03/2019',5.0)

insert into Producto
values
('Disco Duro',90.80,'4 TB-zztop',8,'Seagate','25/02/2020',7.3)

insert into Producto
values
('Disco Duro',50.45,'1TB-x2450',8,'Seagate','25/01/2018',5.3)

insert into Producto
values
('Disco Duro',90.45,'2TB-x3550',8,'Seagate','15/04/2018',7.0)

insert into Producto
values
('Disco Duro',49.80,'SSD240',20,'Kingston','25/05/2018',6.8)

insert into Producto
values
('Disco Duro',67.80,'SSD500 Memo',10,'Kingston','25/04/2020',7.5)

insert into Producto
values
('Disco Duro',179.79,'SSD1000 Memo',5,'Kingston','21/05/2020',8.5)

insert into Producto
values
('Disco Duro',120.80,'HDD-40-1TB',8,'Samsung','15/08/2019',6.9)

insert into Producto
values
('Monitor',195.80,'24kyt',1,'Samsung','25/11/2017',6.9)

insert into Producto
values
('Monitor',230.80,'27ERC',1,'Samsung','12/04/2019',7.8)

insert into Producto
values
('Monitor',240.50,'27Curve Gaming Pro',1,'AOC','19/04/2020',9.5)

insert into Producto
values
('Monitor',520.20,'32Curvemax',1,'AOC','29/05/2020',9.9)

insert into Producto
(nombre,precio,cantidad,marca)
values
('Ratón',5.30,40,'ElGato')

insert into Producto
values
('Ratón',49.90,'Gaming 2.0',10,'Logitech','07/02/2015',8.3)

insert into Producto
values
('Raton',99.85,'Gaming 3.0',10,'Logitech','09/12/2018',8.8)

insert into Producto
values
('Raton',120.35,'Gaming 4.0 4000DPI',1,'Logitech','09/10/2020',8.9)

insert into Producto
values
('Teclado',27.10,'Leds 400',8,'Logitech','03/02/2020',4.2)

insert into Producto
values
('Teclado',43.50,'Leds 600',8,'Logitech','09/06/2020',6.5)

insert into Producto
values
('Tarjeta Wifi',32.50,'4RDC/11',6,'TPLink','03/02/2019',5.0)

insert into Producto
values
('Torre',57.30,'Station 120',1,'NOX','03/03/2020',4.9)

insert into Producto
values
('Torre',98.60,'LED 2000',1,'NOX','03/03/2015',7.5)

insert into Producto
values
('Torre',118.50,'LED 3000',1,'NOX','03/04/2016',7.2)

insert into Producto
values
('Teclado',45.80,'Ergonomic 2',10,'Microsoft','13/03/2019',8.9)

insert into Producto
values
('Impresora',81.80,'Ink 12',1,'HP','18/03/2020',7.5)

insert into Producto
values
('Impresora',50.99,'Paper GTX',1,'HP','01/04/2020',7.1)

insert into Producto
values
('Impresora',110.29,'Paper GTX2',1,'HP','01/03/2020',7.9)

insert into Producto
values
('Plotter',800.49,'',1,'HP','11/04/2020',8.9)

insert into Producto
values
('Televisión',99.99,'22A14',1,'Samsung','11/04/2019',5.9)

insert into Producto
values
('Televisión',399.99,'47EDS',1,'Samsung','11/04/2020',7.5)

insert into Producto
values
('Televisión',2999.89,'55Tx-300',1,'LG','11/05/2020',9.2)

insert into Producto
values
('Televisión',900.05,'47D',1,'LG','11/06/2020',7.2)

insert into Producto
(nombre,precio,cantidad)
values
('Papel Impresora',1.70,16)
```

---

AQUÍ ABAJO EL LOG QUE ME DEVUELVE

```
(1 fila afectada)
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 9
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 13
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 26
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 30
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 34
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 38
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 42
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

(1 fila afectada)
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 50
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 54
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 58
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 62
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 78
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 82
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 86
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 90
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 94
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 98
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 102
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 106
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 110
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

(1 fila afectada)
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 118
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 122
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 167
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 171
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)

(1 fila afectada)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema con las fechas en los scripts.

Primer insert.

```
insert into Producto
(nombre,precio,modelo,cantidad,marca,fabricacion,valoracion)
values
('Placa Base',40.50,'HTX 500',6,'Asus','20200130',7.0)
```

Formato de la fecha insertado yyyymmdd. Esto es perfecto, y no tendrás problemas en ningún servidor, con ningún login.

Segundo script de insert.

```
insert into Producto
values
('Tarjeta gráfica',110.99,'Óptima',4,'Nvidia','29-01-2020 12:30',6.9)
```

Formato de la fecha dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm. Aquí tendrás problemas en función del login.
Reconviertelo a:

```
insert into Producto
values
('Tarjeta gráfica',110.99,'Óptima',4,'Nvidia','20200129 12:30',6.9);
```

Tercero:

```
insert into Producto
values
('Placa base',60.49,'PBX 12',6,'Gigabyte','29/01/2020',7.0)
```

Aquí otro formato diferente: dd/mm/yyyy
Solución simple

```
insert into Producto
values
('Placa base',60.49,'PBX 12',6,'Gigabyte','20200129',7.0);
```

....revisa todos y usa el formato sugerido.

Otra opción, es ponerlos todos en el mismo formato y aplicar una sugerencia de fecha, para las sentencias

```
Set dateformat dmy;
```

Pero usando **yyyymmdd** no te fallarán nunca.

**Nota**: Le puedes anexar las horas al formato.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, entiendo perfectamente lo que me dices. el problema es que no entiendo porque en algunos script si me lo hace y en otros me da error, cuando tienen exactamente el mismo formato de fecha...

Comment: ¿Donde tienen el mismo formato?....No lo tienen. 'Placa Base = yyyyMMdd. Tarjeta gráfica=dd-mm-yyyy. Revisalo, porque no se parecen en nada. Cada fila de inserción tiene un formato diferente.

Comment: El no saber el language que aplica a tú conexión, implica que no sabemos el formato de fecha. Te puse en el ejemplo lo que puedes aplicar. Set dateformat dmy para que te coja dd/mm/yyyy pero los primeros inserts son diferentes.

Comment: El hecho de que en el error tengas muchos fallos de fuera de rango, implica que esta utilizando los meses en vez de los días. Y eso está asociado al login que tiene tú conexión. Donde piensas que es bueno dd/mm el está insertando mm/dd. Puedes comprobarlo con una fila. Si tienes una insertada. Utiliza una función de fecha para saber donde estás. Por ejemplo `Select colFecha, dateAdd(wk,1,colFecha) from tabla;`Eso es que te sume una semana a la fecha. Y así verás si cambia el día o el mes.

Comment: Por ejemplo aquí: insert into Producto
values
('Tarjeta Gráfica',310.80,'Extreme 2.0',6,'AMD','28/02/2019',6.4)

insert into Producto
values
('Tarjeta Gráfica',530.99,'Extreme 3.0 Gaming',6,'AMD','01/03/2020',8.6)  , si tienen el mismo formato de fecha no? y me da por bueno la extreme 3.0 pero no la 2.0 , por eso no entiendo porque siendo mismo formato no lo da por bueno. De todas formas me has aclarado mucho. Soy 100% novato . GRACIAS

Comment: AHHHHHH ya entiendo me está cogiendo el 1º  como mes... mm/dd/yyyy en cambio el formato dd/mm/yyyy no lo da por bueno de ahí el fallo si el dia supera el nº 12.

Comment: Ahora lo que deberías de hacer para no tener esos problemas, como fase 1, es usar siempre yyyyMMdd y eso no te fallará nunca. Luego más adelante ya tienes que buscar como se configura el lenguaje en el login que te da acceso, para entender que idioma te esta aplicando.

Comment: Perfecto, así lo haré.  MUCHAS gracias.